# Why does Restsharp returns different results in .net core vs.net framework?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have two "identical" console applications, one targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2, the other targeting net5.0.

In both applications I am using the exact same method, below a snippet:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://secure.xxxx.yy/login.aspx")
{
    Timeout = -1
};
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
... //snip
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(cookie => cookie.Name == "ASP.NET_SessionId")?.Value);
```

In the net5.0 version, `response.Cookies` contains 3 items (with the one I am looking for), but in the .NET Framework version, `response.Cookies` only contains 1 item (without the one I am looking for)...

What is the reason for this and what are my possibilities to have the same result in .NET Framework?
I am trying to create an Excel VSTO plugin, so I think I am bound to .NET Framework, right?

Below the screenshots from within VS:

[image: .net5.0 (good) response]

[image: .net framework (bad) response]

Below the response from fiddler (they are identical for both .net versions):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /xxxxx.eu/authorized/home.aspx
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0hslsdigt5kpha30rtk4veoc; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: .ASPNET=F1B8BEB09F20EF52B75BBA81B5535EC580B873E5A65F43AEC779C27C50730998582DC814DCAF194206636ACFBA706E2DE90371071F9AEB6B03E0C8ACF0BDE44CB3844230CC2143B2307EBB4889C12764167E15CA3240A74B430156205F6CD53AC8982EBE8EF3FE51E09862DF5AB15A7145F8451357515C48D3F3F09D48E7D890; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 22 Apr 2021 11:40:28 GMT
Content-Length: 156
```

Comment: I would first try debugging this through someything like Fiddler to make sure both requests are indeed the same and then verify the returned cookies in both cases match what you get from RestSharp.

Comment: @phuzi, I have checked with Fiddler: both requests return 3 cookies (while only one is accessible in the .NET Framework version)

Comment: Could you add the details to the question, including details from Fiddler?

Comment: I have added some screenshots from VS; I will try to do the same for the fiddler results

Comment: Wondering if the Cookies you can't see are marked http-only this would normally mean that they aren't visible to JavaScript but wonder if RestSharp is doing something similar

Comment: @phuzi, they are indeed marked as httponly (but that goes for both .net versions)

Comment: @phuzi: your comment made me search on this httponly thing, and I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303065/cookie-missing-in-restsharp-response and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9002061/1381490

Answer (score 1):

as @phuzi mentioned, the cookies are not available since they are set as httponly.

adding a cookiejar to the client, I am able to get the required cookie:

```
var site = new Uri("https://secure.xxxx.yy/login.aspx");
var client = new RestClient(site)

CookieContainer _cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
client.CookieContainer = _cookieJar;
//.... execute the request
var cookies = _cookieJar.GetCookies(site);
```